# How can i add confidence intervals to predictions generated using add_predicition fucntion in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Ive generated predictions, using add_predictions and tried to add confidence intervals as below. I would like to plot the predictions, with confidence intervals, so have tried to merge, but not been successful. Any ideas?

```
preds_NBM_2 <- expand_grid(equations = seq(1,20),
                      selfcites = 9,
                      pages = 9,
                      journal = "Evolution")
                    
preds_NBM_22 <- add_predictions(preds_NBM_2, NBM, 
type = "response")

preds_NBM_22_CI <-  predict (NBM2, newdata = 
preds_NBM_22, se.fit = T)
cbind(
  pred_M_1a$fit - pred_M_1a$se.fit * qnorm(0.975),
  pred_M_1a$fit + pred_M_1a$se.fit * qnorm(0.975)
 ) %>%plogis()

total <- cbind(preds_NBM_22, preds_NBM_22_CI)
```

Comment: Hi, to help us answer please add the packages you are using, we also need to know what `NBM` and `NBM2` are

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example of your problem, e.g share your data with `dput`